# Windows NT 3.51 title bar buttons

Tags: windows

What is exact meaning Windows NT 3.51 title bar buttons?
Arrow up is maximize and arrow down minimize?
And left button is close?
Its my assumption right?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upward-pointing arrow does indeed maximise the window, and the downward-pointing arrow minimises it.

The “minus” provides access to the window menu; double-clicking it will close the window. The menu for an application window is this:

[image: Windows NT 3 window menu]

The menu for an MDI document window (such as a program group in Program Manager) is this:

[image: Windows NT 3 MDI document menu]

Applications can add their own entries to these menus.

These exact buttons were used in [Windows 3.0](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/win30), [Windows 3.1](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/win31) (and variants), [Windows NT 3.1](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/winnt31), [Windows NT 3.51](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/winnt351), and [OS/2 1.3](https://guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/msos21301). I think the two menu buttons are supposed to be reminiscent of their keyboard short-cuts, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: I always interpreted the symbol on the left-hand button as a handle (like on a filing-cabinet drawer) that you'd pull on to reveal the menu (ok, at that point the metaphor collapses).

Comment: Ah yes, I can see that; I always thought of them as “spacebar” and “minus” (because of the corresponding short-cuts, Alt+Spacebar and Alt+-).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a link, but I remember Raymond Chen (or one of the other Microsoft bloggers he linked to) treating the "meant to be a spacebar" interpretation for application windows as unarguably correct. (It stuck in my mind because it was such a "Huh. I never thought of it that way." moment.)

Comment: Jensen Harris wrote about the space bar/hyphen connection in 2006: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jensenh/you-windows-3-1-lovers

Comment: The system menu(s) still exists; the icon has been replaced by the application-specific icons since Windows 95. Some applications might omit the icon entirely but the menu can usually still be accessed (unless directly suppressed by the application) using the same keystrokes.